# Iterate though array of int by prime numbers at C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I leave the complete code so that you can understand the context.
My problem is on line 53 (it says "HERE HERE...")...
The purpose of the code is to decompose a number(n) dividing it by prime numbers and printing at all in a chart.
Basically the problem is how to iterate through an int array by prime numbers.
I hope find help...
Please let me know any feedback

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>
    using namespace std;

    int main (){
        char slot;
        int primo, div = 0;
        int m;

        //Ask to user, the size(slot) of our Array (memory[])
        cout << "Escoga la memoria que mas se acomode a su necesidad y RAM: \t\n"
             << " A) 512 slots\n"
             << " B) 128 slots\n"
             << " C) 64 slots\n"
             << " > ";  
        cin >> slot;

        if (slot == 'a' || 'A') 
        {
            m = 512;
        }
        if (slot == 'b' || 'B')
        {
            m = 128;
        }
        if (slot == 'c' || 'C')
        {
            m = 64;
        }

        int memory[m];

        // Storage in Array memory all prime numbers between 1 and m.
        for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
        {
            primo = 0;
            for (div = 2; div < i - 1 && primo == 0; div++)
            {
                if (i % div == 0) primo = 1;
            }
            if (primo == 0) 
                memory[i] = i;
        }

        //Ask to user, for give a number. 
        //n = The number that we gonna descompose arithmetically
        cout << "Inserte un numero: ";
        cin >> n;   
        cout << "   | " << n << "\n";
             << "-------\n";
//HERE HERE HERE 
        //Iterate through memory [] printing the descompose of n
        for ("HERE I NEED ITERATE FROM"  memory[2] "UNTIL" memory[63])
        {
            do
            {
                n /= j;
                cout << " " << j << " | " << n << "\n";
            }while((n % j) == 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is memory ? an C style array ? a C++ vector or array ?

Comment: `for(int i=2; i<m; i++)  array[i] = 1;` Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: In your own words, what do you expect `if (slot == 'a' || 'A')` to do? And why?

Comment: @Max memory[] is an array of int (int memory[]) that I made for storage all prime numbers until the variable n.

Comment: `if (slot == 'a' || 'A')` - Tell me exactly what the `||` operator does. Don't just say it's the OR operator. Tell me what it inputs and what it outputs.

Comment: @CvrlosKenobi, If I got you right, `for(int i=2; i<64; i++) { //do something with memory[i]; }`

Or `for(int i=2; i<=63; i++) { //do something with memory[i]; } `

Comment: @KarlKnechtel If user types A or a, variable slot will be equal to 512.

Comment: Okay, and how do I type `A or a`? I know how to type `A`, and I know how to type `a`, but that doesn't equate to there being a thing called `A or a` that I can type.

Comment: The `||` operator isn't the same as the English word "or". You're trying to read code as English, but that's not how C++ expressions work. The `||` operator takes two **boolean** arguments and returns the *logical OR* of the arguments. Logical OR != English word "or".

Comment: @BessieTheCow Oh I got your point. So temporally I will only assign a default value to `m` . And thank you.
But I'm searching help with the for loop from below.

Comment: Search your favorite C++ reference for `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`.  Convert your character to a know case.  Make one comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

const int SIZE = 10;

int main()
{
    int m = 8;

    std::array<int, SIZE> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    for (auto i : arr) {  // How to iterate all elements of std::array
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Another way to do the same thing (print all elements)
    std::copy(arr.begin(), arr.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    // Getting to your actual question
    if (m < arr.size()) {
        for (int i = 2; i < m; ++i) {
            std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the whole array, change it to start at index "2" and go to variable "m" and you've got it.